# player collision does not work with objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an endless runner game and i have a question about my player colliding with so,e obstacles, I used Raycast but when i try to debug this collision doesn't occur.

Here my player Code.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;

    public float speed;
    public float jumpHeight;
    private float jumpVelocity;
    public float gravity;

    public float rayRadius;
    public LayerMask layer;
    
    public float horizontalSpeed;
    private bool isMovingLeft;
    private bool isMovingRight;
    private bool isDead;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();  
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
   { 
        Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward * speed;

        if(controller.isGrounded)
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                jumpVelocity = jumpHeight;

            }
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)&& transform.position.x  < 3.58f && !isMovingRight)
            {
                isMovingRight = true;
                StartCoroutine(RightMove());

            }
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)&& transform.position.x > -3.58f && !isMovingLeft)
            {
                isMovingLeft = true;
                StartCoroutine(LeftMove());

            }
        }
        else
        {
            jumpVelocity -= gravity;
        }

        OnCollision();

        direction.y = jumpVelocity;

        controller.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    IEnumerator LeftMove()
    {
        for(float i = 0; i < 10; i += 0.1f)
        {
            controller.Move(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * horizontalSpeed);
            yield return null;
        }
        isMovingLeft = false;

    }

    IEnumerator RightMove()
    {
        for (float i = 0; i < 10; i += 0.1f)
        {
            controller.Move(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * horizontalSpeed);
            yield return null;
        }
        isMovingRight = false;

    }

    void OnCollision()
        //The player will collide with obstacles that have a specific type of layer and dead.
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, rayRadius, layer) && !isDead)
        {

            Debug.Log("GameOver!");
            speed = 0;

            jumpHeight = 0;
            isDead = true;


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The obvious candidates for errors are that you set up either `rayRadius` or `layer` wrong on your object. Or perhaps the objects you are trying to check against don't have their colliders set up correctly. It's not really possible to tell from this code alone. And I also don't really understand why you are manually performing collision detection via raycasts instead of using the built-in colliders

Comment: It must have been an error in the player's collider, but thanks. Doesn't characterController collision look better using RayCast?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "look better" but I suspect the answer to be "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using raycast inside OnCollision function. You can do this with very much by following these steps:

Add a tag to your obstacles let say its "Obstacle"
Add collider to them
Check when you collide with someone that if it is obstacle or not if yes then you can call your dead function.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.transform.CompareTag("Obstacle")){

        Debug.Log("GameOver!");
        speed = 0;

        jumpHeight = 0;
        isDead = true;
  }
}
```

In this way you can detect collision with super ease instead of using raycast.